# Linked List Data Structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to make a Huffman tree so I created a linked list structure. I am trying to print out the frequencies automatically instead of the following way.

```
cout << root->left->frequency << endl;
cout << root->left->left->frequency << endl; 
cout << root->left->left->left->frequency << endl; 
cout << root->left->left->left->left->frequency << endl;
```

How do I print out the following using a for loop or any other method ? I don't want to keep adding `left->` to access the next one.

In case the structure is needed

```
struct binaryTreeNode
{
string binarycode;
char letter;
int frequency;
int level;

binaryTreeNode *left;
binaryTreeNode *right;
binaryTreeNode()
{
    binarycode = "";
    frequency = 1;
    level = 1;
    letter = NULL;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've built the tree correctly, this should print the entire leftmost chain until reaching the leaf -

```
binaryTreeNode *p = root;
while (p->left != NULL) {
    p = p->left;
    cout << p->frequency << endl;
}
```

or if you want to stop after N iterations, just add a counter.

Note that your code doesn't check for the validity of the pointers in each level.